How to get content of a confluence page or a subsection via it's URL and not page ID?
Confluence REST API offers a way to get the content of the whole page with it's page id:
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/v2/api-group-page/#api-group-page
However, this doesn't solve my problem. I have a use case in which I only have URL of a page and not aware of it's page ID (nor I wish to put in efforts to get it). That URL might be of the whole page, or as well as a subsection, a comment etc from that page. Nor I want to click on the 3 dots to get the page id.
I only want the content from the portion specified by the URL.
The problem is, I am not able to get the content without knowing the page ID.
I have also tried Python API for Confluence, however, it again needs the page ID.
https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/confluence.html
One can say, what's stopping you from getting a page ID from the URL. Well, the key problem is, once I have the page ID, I can only retrieve the whole page and have no info about subsection. But how do I cater to getting content from a subsection of the page?
